# NSDate: Convert UTC value to Military Time Zone Value

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter

The military way of writing date and time, aka Military Date Time Group or DTG, has the following format:

DDHHMMZMONYY

where DD = Day

HH = Hour (24 hour)

MM = Minutes

Z = Military Time Zone

MON = Month

YY = Year

For example: Dec 27, 2015, 05:48 +0200 will, in the military format, be:

270548BDEC15

with B being equal to UTC+2 (+0200)  (see http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/military for UTC and corresponding Military Time Zones)

I am trying to accomplish this military style/formatting, and currently I have the following in Swift:

```
let StartDTG = NSDate()
let StartDTGDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

StartDTGDateFormatter.dateFormat = "ddkkmmZZZLLLyy"

let tempConvertedTAStartDTG = StartDTGDateFormatter.stringFromDate(StartDTG)

let UpperCaseTAStartDTG = tempConvertedTAStartDTG.uppercaseString

TAStartDTG.text = String(UpperCaseTAStartDTG)
```

This code will take the current date and time and display it in the text field as follows:

```
270548+0200DEC15
```

QUESTION:  How can I convert the ZZZ-value to represent the equivalent military value so that I can get this?

270548**B**DEC15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary with your custom key and values and just get the timezone property secondsFromGMT, divide it by 3600 to get the offset in hours and use it as your dictionary key to get the correspondent time zone values:

```
extension NSDate {
    struct Date {
        static let militaryZones: [Int:String] = {
            return [-12: "Y", -11: "X", -10: "W", -9: "V", -8: "U", -7: "T", -6: "S", -05: "R", -4: "Q", -3: "P", -2: "O", -1: "N", 0: "Z", 1: "A", 2: "B", 3: "C", 4: "D", 5: "E", 6: "F", 7: "G", 8: "H", 9: "I", 10: "K", 11: "L", 12: "M"]}()
        static let formatterMilitary: NSDateFormatter = {
            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601)
            formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
            formatter.dateFormat = "ddkkmm LLLyy"
            return formatter
        }()
    }
    var militaryTimeZone: String {
        return Date.militaryZones[NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().secondsFromGMT/3600] ?? ""
    }
    var militaryTime: String {
        return Date.formatterMilitary.stringFromDate(self)
            .componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
            .joinWithSeparator(militaryTimeZone)
            .uppercaseString
    }
}
NSDate().militaryTime      // "270455ODEC15"
NSDate().militaryTimeZone  // "O"
```

Comment: Oh boy, this is beautiful!  

Thank you very much, @Leo Dabus!

Comment: Just a note in case somebody else wants to use this:  I've tested for countries with half hour and 45-minute time zones (eg. Afghanistan (+04:30)), and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I speak swift with a stutter, but my advice would be to use a standard format...

```
StartDTGDateFormatter.dateFormat = "ddkkmm X LLLyy"
```

... the "X" will give hours from GMT +00...+12, -01..-11.  The spaces will be useful for parsing...

```
let UpperCaseTAStartDTG = tempConvertedTAStartDTG.uppercaseString
let components = UpperCaseTAStartDTG.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
```

... which will provide an array like this...

```
(
    262050,
    "-08",  // California, USA
    DEC15
)
```

...the standard bit, the hours from GMT, and the remainder of the standard bit.  It should be straight-forward to develop a function that takes the second element of that array and answers the military zone.

Note that array responds to `componentsJoinedByString()` so it should be easy to put it back together.

Comment: Building on your answer, I actually did get a solution that worked - so thanks!  However, the answer by Leo Dabus works perfectly "out of the box".